# Why are my profile pages not generating which I click on 'submit'?

Tags: user-profile

does anyone know what I am doing wrong here? I am trying to create profile pages for each user, but when I click the submit button, it doesn't take me to the user's page.

This is my form code:

```
<form method="get" accept-charset="UTF-8" class="form"    action="/profile/{{ user }}"> <input type="hidden" name="action" value="users/login">

<input id="loginName" type="text" name="loginName" placeholder="username"
    value="{{ craft.session.rememberedUsername }}">

<input id="password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="secret password">

<input type="submit" value="Login" class="login_enter">

<label class="remember">
    <input type="checkbox" name="rememberMe" value="1" checked>
    Remember me
</label>


{% if errorMessage is defined %}
    <p class="remember">{{ errorMessage }}</p>
{% endif %}
```

I have a profile folder and an _profile template. I also added a custom route in the admin panel with the following URI

```
    profile/*
```

And a link to the template

```
    profile/_profile
```

The profile index file looks like this:

```
{% set users = craft.users %}
{% for user in users %}
<a href="/profile/{{ user }}">{{ user }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

And the _profile file looks like this

```
{% extends "_account_register_layout" %}
{% set title = "account" %}
{% set user = craft.users.username( craft.request.segment(2) ).first() %}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the action and redirect as hidden inputs, see below:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="users/saveUser">
    <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="/profile/{{ currentUser.username }}">
```

Comment: I accidentally deleted my stack exchange profile - stupid, I know. Just wanted to say thanks @Brad. It worked :)

Comment: Glad to hear that!